# Importing multiple files into a single, merged data frame in R

Tags: r, file, csv, import

I have 8 CSV files all in the same directory, and need them importing into a single data frame in R. They all follow the same naming convention, "dataUK_1.csv", "dataUK_2.csv" etc., and have the exact same structure in terms of columns.

I've managed to create a vector of all the file names (including the full directory) by using:

```
files = list.files("/Users/iarwain/Data", pattern=".csv", full.names=T)
```

I'm just not sure how to pass these names to the read.csv command so that it loops 8 times, importing each file and adding its content as new rows into a single data frame, so that the end result is one data frame containing all rows of data from the 8 CSVs.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a loop. You want `lapply`.

```
file_list <- list.files("/Users/iarwain/Data", pattern=".csv", full.names=T)


combined_files <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file_list, read.csv))
```

Translation: apply the function `read.csv` over each item in the list `file_list`. The output is a list. Call the function `rbind` on all of the output, and assign it to `combined_files`

Comment: For some reason it's prompting me for some extra input (the > turns to a +) - even when I change files to file_list (which I assume is what you meant in the second line)

Comment: Oh dear it didn't even occur to me that it was only a missing bracket, it's been one of those days... thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In tidyverse you can just add a pipe and a `map_df()`

```
file_list <- list.files("/Users/iarwain/Data", pattern=".csv", full.names=T) %>%
    map_df(read_csv(.))
```

Specifically, as Hadley describes [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html) (about halfway down):

> `map_df(x, f)` is effectively the same as `do.call("rbind", lapply(x, f))` but under the hood is much more efficient.

and a thank you to Jake Kaupp for introducing me to `map_df()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640132/importing-multiple-csv-files-with-variable-column-types-into-r).