# Importing multiple .csv files with variable column types into R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I properly build an lapply to read (from out of one directory) all the .csv files, load all the columns as strings and then bind them into one data frame.

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555961/5088194), I have a way to get all the .csv files loaded and bound into a dataframe. Unfortunately they are getting hung up on the variablity of how the columns are getting type cast. Thus giving me this error:

> Error: Can not automatically convert from character to integer in
>   column

I have tried supplementing the code with the [arguments for data type](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/column-types.html) and am trying to just keep everything as characters; I am getting stuck now on being able to properly get my lapply 'loop' to effectively reference the subject of each cycle of its 'loop'.

```
srvy1 <- structure(list(RESPONSE_ID = 584580L, QUESTION_ID = 328L, SURVEY_ID = 2324L, 
           AFF_ID_INV_RESP = 5L), .Names = c("RESPONSE_ID", "QUESTION_ID", 
                                             "SURVEY_ID", "AFF_ID_INV_RESP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                  -1L))

srvy2 <- structure(list(RESPONSE_ID = 584580L, QUESTION_ID = 328L, SURVEY_ID = 2324L, 
           AFF_ID_INV_RESP = "bovine"), .Names = c("RESPONSE_ID", "QUESTION_ID", 
                                                   "SURVEY_ID", "AFF_ID_INV_RESP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        -1L))    

files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
tbl = lapply(files, read_csv(files, col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))) %>% bind_rows
```

Is there an easy fix for this that I can keep in tidyverse, or must I drop down a level and go into openly building the for loop myself - per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39675290/5088194).

Comment: and the downvote is for what exactly?

Comment: Most likely due to not providing a reproducible example, with data.  You have some errors in your code.  It should be `lapply(fies, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))`

Comment: I would supply `head(x,5)` of two of the files, create a list from those and `dput` the results and paste them here.

Comment: `tbl = lapply(files, read_csv(col_types = cols(.default = col_character())))` gets the following error _Error in inherits(x, "connection") : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default_ and this `tbl = lapply(files, read_csv(files, col_types = cols(.default = col_character())))` gets this _Error in switch(tools::file_ext(path), gz = gzfile(path, ""), bz2 = bzfile(path,  : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("\n", x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used_ which typically means that I need a rowwise call.

Comment: The `lapply` should be the form `lapply(x, FUN, ...)` where ... is the arguments passed to FUN.   You're filling the arguments within FUN.  It should be `lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))`

Comment: readr doesn't like the `lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = col_character())%>% bind_rows)` as it gives this warning: _Error: col_types must be NULL, a list or a string_ but it is very happy with the `tbl = lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>% bind_rows`. You're the bomb! Can you throw your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `lapply` should be the form `lapply(x, FUN, ...)` where `...` is the arguments passed to `FUN`. You're filling the arguments within FUN. It should be `lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = "c"))`

If you like a `tidyverse` solution:

```
files %>%
  map_df(~read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(.default = "c")))
```

Which will bind the whole thing into a data frame at the end.

Comment: thank you. I have been struggling with this for hours.