# Read multiple csv files when Date Column is character format

Tags: r, lapply, readr

I am using the `readr` and `bind_rows()` function to read multiple csvs.

Example code:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df = lapply(c(
  "df 4-11-17.csv",
  "df 4-12-17.csv",
  "df 4-13-17.csv"),
  read_csv) %>% bind_rows()
```

When I do this I get an error stating:

```
Error: Can not automatically convert from character to Date in column "Date".
```

The first column name is "Date" and it is in a character format currently. this is what it looks like when I do str(df) for the first column.

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   961751 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Date                       : chr  "4/10/2017" "4/10/2017" "4/10/2017" 
"4/10/2017" ...
```

If anyone knows how to read multiple csv files at the same time where it disregards the format of the column such as the Date column, it would be helpful!

Comment: If you want it to parse for you, you'll need to specify the format in `col_date`; from what you've shown, it's not obvious if it's mdY or dmY.

Comment: This is literally the very first item in the readr package documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing multiple .csv files with variable column types into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640132/importing-multiple-csv-files-with-variable-column-types-into-r)

Answer (score 0):

[Importing multiple .csv files with variable column types into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640132/importing-multiple-csv-files-with-variable-column-types-into-r)

This answered the question:

add

```
read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>% bind_rows()
```