# Import many csv files into a vector - A simple way?

Tags: r, csv, vector, import

I am working with 600 csv files. I want to import them all into a vector. I can write code for each, one at a time like this (using just 4 of the files as an example):

```
    ## Import for CSV files
    csv1 <- read.csv("csvFiles/csv1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    csv1.df <- as.data.frame(csv1)
    names(csv1.df) <- c("text")
    csv1.vc <- paste(csv1.df$text, collapse=" ") 
    
    csv2 <- read.csv("csvFiles/csv2.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    csv2.df <- as.data.frame(csv2)
    names(csv2.df) <- c("text")
    csv2.vc <- paste(csv2.df$text, collapse=" ") 
    
    csv3 <- read.csv("csvFiles/csv3.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    csv3.df <- as.data.frame(csv3)
    names(csv3.df) <- c("text")
    csv3.vc <- paste(csv3.df$text, collapse=" ") 
    
    csv4 <- read.csv("csvFiles/csv4.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    csv4.df <- as.data.frame(csv4)
    names(csv4.df) <- c("text")
    csv4.vc <- paste(csv4.df$text, collapse=" ") 
    
    ## Combine all vectors into a single data frame 
    final.vc <- c(csv1.vc, csv2.vc, csv3.vc, csv4.vc)
    Encoding(final.vc) <- "UTF-8"
```

I know there must be a way for R to import all the files in my directory and combine them into the vector how I want, without having to write 4 lines of code for each of the 600 csv files. I think it's something like this, but I'm just not getting it right. I'm quite new to coding, R, and R-script

```
## Import for CSV files
    files <- list.files(path = "csvFiles", pattern = ".csv$",  full.names = TRUE)
    
    csv2vector <- function(company){
           
    csvfile <- read.csv(file="filename", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    csfvile.df <- as.data.frame(csvfile)
    names(csvfile.df) <- c("text")
    csvfile.vc <- paste(csvfile.df$text, collapse=" ") # Creates a single vector
   
## Combine all vectors into a single data frame 
    companyvec <- c(company)
    names(companyvec) <- c("company")
        final.vc <- c(companyvec)
    }
    lapply(files, csv2vector)
```

Any help and advice is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Your result is probably a list of vectors, right? If that's true, just add `do.call(c, lapply(files, csv2vector))` and you're done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing multiple files into a single, merged data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245156/importing-multiple-files-into-a-single-merged-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: @mhovd thanks for pointing to this duplicate. I believe, there is a more "famous one" :)